# Decorator for pubsub subscribe: how to add the parameters from the function to the wrapper

Tags: python, python-3.6, publish-subscribe, python-decorators

I just started using decorators in python and thought it might be useful to write a decorator for `pubsub.subscribe`

I'm using Python 3.6 so `functools.wraps` should make the wrapper having the same signature as the wrapped function, but `pub.sendMessage` still complains about the additional unknown argument.

```
from pubsub import pub
from functools import wraps

def subscribe(message):
    def subscribe_deco(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        pub.subscribe(wrapper, message)
        return wrapper
    return subscribe_deco


@subscribe('testmessage')
def test(bar='empty'):
    print('foo ' + bar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test('bar')
    pub.sendMessage('testmessage')
    pub.sendMessage('testmessage', bar='decorated')
```

Result:

```
foo bar
foo empty
pubsub.core.topicargspec.SenderUnknownMsgDataError: Some optional args unknown in call to sendMessage('('testmessage',)', bar): bar
```

---

Update:

I just realized that the inner wrapper is useless and I can just subscribe to the decorated function directly. But I'm not sure then, if I even need a decorator in that case ...

```
def subscribe(message):
  def subscribe_deco(func):
    pub.subscribe(func, message)
    return func
  return subscribe_deco
```

Comment: After your update, do you have the same issue?

Comment: Also, the decorator-based subscription will work with free functions and static/class methods, but not with instance methods, because the decoration-based subscription activates at import time, typically before any of the listener objects (and hence their bound methods) exist.

Comment: Ohhh .. good point! Haven't thought that far yet! And yes, it's working with the updated version. Do you have any idea why pubsub isn't accepting the wrapped method?

Comment: I must say I'm a little surprised it doesn't work, but I wouldnt be surprised if the free function is a problem. Try to manually subscribe (and remove decorator), does it work?

Comment: That way it works. Strange .. shouldn't the decorated function ```test``` be the same like wrapper inside the decorator? At least, that's how I understood that decorators should work.

Comment: I would have to dig into the code that validate message data vs listener signature and try it with both decorated and undecorated listeners. Could you submit a bug (github.com/schollii/pypubsub)? I'm extremely busy with other stuff so any help in identifying the problematic line of code would be hugely appreciated by pypubsub users.

Comment: Of course, no Problem!